# Handling serialized array from ajax in PHP

Tags: php

I'm sending the following data from a jQuery Ajax script to PHP (taken from the network tab):

```
question: How are you?
1: Good
2: Okay
3: Bad
4: Very bad
qNo: 1
question: How old are you?
5: 1-19
6: 20-29
7: 30-39
8: 40+
qNo: 2
```

Two questions, four answers to each, one number assigned to each question. It can however be up to 50 questions.

What I can't figure out is how to separate them properly in my PHP file and I realized only now that there may be something bad with the setup. I want to separate them so that I can insert them into one row in the database like:

```
question: How are you?
1: Good
2: Okay
3: Bad
4: Very bad
qNo: 1
```

..as one entry and:

```
question: How old are you?
5: 1-19
6: 20-29
7: 30-39
8: 40+
qNo: 2
```

..as the other entry. I can only figure out how to do it one at a time, but that'd be a ridiculously long code strip with 50 questions with four answers each.

How do I go about solving this in the easiest way possible?

I'm not sure if it's interesting in this case, but this is the ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitQuestionnaire").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"php/insertion.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: $("#questionnaireFormData").serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    // TBA
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Responding to comment:

```
question=Example%20question&1=One&2=Two&3=Three&4=Four&qNo=1&question=Another%20example%20for%20question%20two&5=An%20answer&6=Another%20answer&7=A%20non-answer&8=A%20fourth%20answer&qNo=2
```

Comment: Why are you submitting ALL answers with the question? You should be just submitting the Question ID and the Selected Answer.

Comment: @imvain2 This is for creating a form for others to use, so the possible answers will be presented to another user.

Comment: In javascript try `console.log($("#questionnaireFormData").serialize())` then adding the response from your console to your question.

Comment: @imvain2 It has been edited in

Comment: if you want to do it right and not serialise/json encode you need to do relationships should have 3 tables a *questions* table with the question and id, a questions_answer table, with id, question_id, and the answer (that's the multiple). when a user answers you have a user table and a questions_user_answer, which contains question_id and question_answer_id, i.e question could be number 4 and user answered the answer 3 (which could be id 23 its irrelevant).. the 1. to 5. should not be part of the question but simply an iteration count

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes but I thought I was taking the easy way by simply packing it into one table and using only one insertion. I understand I may have been wrong.

Comment: If you have repeated inputs with the same name in the form, you need to give them array-style names: `name="question[]"`

Comment: @MoMononoke, this is part PHP but mostly a javascript/HTML problem. You will want to go back and redo how you handle your question creation process. As Barmar mentioned, using array style names but that will get weird with the answers. I would have an array/object that will hold the questions and their answers, then submit that instead of HTML input via serialize.

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you. Was hoping there was an easier way, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: sidenote its 2020 you should perhaps look into a framework like vue, here is an example: https://playcode.io/674550/

Comment: @MoMononoke a simple solution is have every question submitted to PHP upon creation. Instead of submitting them all at once.